# Могут ли переменные окружения измениться извне?

Tags: c

Программирую на си под линукс. Интересует вопрос "стабильности" переменных окружения.
Допустим, при запуске программы, я прочитал интересующие меня переменные окружения с момощью getenv() или из envp:

`int main( int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[] )`

Допустим, через некоторое время в своём коде я захочу обратиться к переменным снова. Могу я быть уверен в том, что значения переменных окружения, которые были получены при запуске, остались прежними и ничто извне не могло их изменить? Есть ли смысл объявить свои переменные на стаке или выделить память на куче и скопировать значения нужных мне переменныех окружения?

Comment: Если сами, вызывая [setenv()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) не меняли, то только теоретически, используя ту же [технику](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html), что применяяет отладчик (но в таком случае и копирование никаких гарантий не даст)